# How to automatically fill in a module input using a list

Tags: python, module

I have a basic python module that I want to run repeatedly using a list but the variable is declared as an input and is not able to be pre-defined in the module.

`def testing():   var = input("Please enter something: ")   print("You entered: " + var)`

If I run through the module in a loop with different strings:

`for i in ['lol','lel','lal']:   testing()   print(i)`

the different strings will not be used as input and instead be printed after. Is there any way to have those strings become the input for the module?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you try to achieve and why you can't change the input if you don't necessarily need it. You could try doing something like this and send an empty string when you actually need an input?

```
def testing(input):  
   if input == "": 
      var = input("Please enter something: ")  
      print("You entered: " + var)
   else:
      print("You entered: " + input)

for i in ['lol','lel','lal']:   
   testing()   
   print(i)
```

Comment: I do realize it's an easy fix to make the variable declared in the module rather than calling for input from the user. I was more curious about if there's a way to pre-define the input for a module where the variable is not declared using a list of strings